# Problem in Cross-Compilation-of-CGAL-for-Android

Tags: android, cross-compiling, cgal

I am trying to cross compile CGAL for Android following https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/wiki/Cross-Compilation-of-CGAL-for-Android

I had the following error when executing cmake :

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/Platform/Android-Common.cmake:54 (message):
  Android: STL 'gnustl_static' include directory not found:
```

Anyone have a clue ?

(using kubuntu 16.10, CGAL 4.13, android 28)

Answer (score 0):

I read that gnustl_static has been recently replaced by c++_static. My guess is you should add

`-DCMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE="c++_static"`

to your cmake configuration options. Source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE.html
Please let me know if that works and I'll update the wiki.